# Редирект старых url

Tags: .htaccess

Было очень много ссылок типа

```
site.ru/catalog/category/product
```

Теперь нам нужно делать редирект если присутствует **catalog/** на главную страницу.
Пожалуйста подскажите возможно ли сделать такой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Если сайт на PHP, то можно в index.php как вариант:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/catalog/') !== false) {

    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: ".str_replace('/catalog/','/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    exit();

}
```